# Adding data to two cells and creating new columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bunch of data and each has two cells. I want to automatically paste that data in the first and second row and continue below the columns until the data is rendered.

The question is how can I add values to two cells on the same column using the `getLastRow` function?

If you know any other way to do it instead of using `getLastRow`, please let me know.

```
var lastRow = sheet10.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet10.getLastColumn();

sheet10.getRange(lastRow +1, 1).setValue('row') 
sheet10.getRange(lastColumn +1, 2).setValue('column')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this sample code below to automatically add a sample data "Banana" in the first and second row (2 cells) after the last row and then adds a new column:

**Recommendation:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet10 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet10.getLastRow()+1;
  var lastColumn = sheet10.getLastColumn()+1;
  sheet10.getRange(1, lastColumn).setValue('Column');
  for(var x=lastRow; x<=lastRow+1; x++){ //Loop to add data twice (in the first and second row) after the last row that has a data
    sheet10.getRange(x, 1).setValue('Banana');
  }
}
```

Here's the sample sheet when the code is not run yet:

[image]

Here's the result after running the code:

[image]